# Ubuntu 20.04 sound is not working on Lenovo Legion Slim 7i

Tags: 20.04, sound, lenovo

I have a problem with sound on my laptop. I tried every solution, but it still does not work. Sound works perfectly in my headphones connected through jack, but speakers do not work. Even the bar in Sound settings is visible.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Did you unplug the headphones when you use speakers?

Comment: Hello, of course, yes. I just tried to see if there is the same problem with headphones. I tried to update the kernel with so many fixes, but it still doesn't work. I have a Realtek ACL287 sound card and I read that it has a problem. But don't understand why it is not fixed in the new kernel update when the problem is here a few months at least.

Comment: This is a genuine question. The culprit is in some drivers not being available to play sounds for ubuntu. Unfortunately I don't have a solution for you as I am facing the same thing.

Comment: There is a bug affecting Legion Slim 7i: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555